# Jython throws java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError intermittently

Tags: python, jython

I am a java person not well versed in jython or python.  So pardon my ignorance if this is a basic question.

I am using `jython 2.5, python 2.5 and jre 1.7`.

Intermittently, the jython interpreter fails to start, and is throwing an error like:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>    -        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:258)
>    -        at org.python.core.PySystemState.initStaticFields(PySystemState.java:912)
>    -        at org.python.core.PySystemState.doInitialize(PySystemState.java:882)
>    -        at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:800)
>    -        at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:750)
>    -        at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:743)
>    -        at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:150)
>    -        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:129)
>    - Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>    -        at org.python.core.PyObject._cmpeq_unsafe(PyObject.java:1362)
>    -        at org.python.core.PyObject._eq(PyObject.java:1456)
>    -        at org.python.core.PyObject.equals(PyObject.java:244)
>    -        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:475)
>    -        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
>    -        at org.python.core.PyType.fromClass(PyType.java:1317)
>    -        at org.python.core.PyType.fromClass(PyType.java:1275)
>    -        at org.python.core.PyEllipsis.(PyEllipsis.java:14)
>    -        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
>    -        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
>    -        ... 7 more

I did search the net, however I did not find any helpful information.

If anyone of you has solved this issue, please share.

Thanks
Ashoka

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I did further analysis, tried to re-build the jython.jar.  I looked at the stack-trace and doInitialize is getting called only during the failure.... and that get called only when either when Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); is null or PySystemState.class.getClassLoader(); is null...           But I am not sure why this occurs....And one more important thing is that there are many jython-jvms running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update.  We found this was due to an jython initialization bug with jython.  Our in-house expert found this.

PySystemState initStaticFields and initBuildins initialize PyTypes before Py.False and Py.True are initialized. Intermittently this leads to ExceptionInInitializerError thrown due to a NullPointer exception in PyObject._cmpeq_unsafe.

Root cause of the problem is that PyType.fromClass stores all types in a HashSet exposedTypes. If during initialization two PyTypes end up having the same hashCode, the HashSet uses the method equals. Some methods called by PyObject.equals return Py.True/Py.False (see PyObject._is) which aren't initialized as first PyTypes...

We have seen this error only on AIX systems and with an application that generated +10000 Jython runs per day.

More on this bug http://bugs.jython.org/issue2163

Solution:One fix would be to ensure PyTrue and PyFalse get initialized right at the start of the PyType initialization. Rebuilt the jython.jar

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to read the exception.

About seven lines in, your exception says "Caused by: `java.lang.NullPointerException`".  I would focus on that.  Where is the `null` coming from?

Also note that your stack trace is missing some lines at the end, where it says "... 7 more".  This makes it hard to read the exception, because we don't know what the missing lines say.  See if you can find a way to show the missing lines, in case they are helpful.